# How can I execute multiple Oracle SQL statements with .NET

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

As a part of our build process we want to execute SQL Scripts consisting of DDL and DML statements against a fresh database instance.

ADO.NET Connection/Command can't handle this without parsing and splitting the scripts.

The `sqlplus` command line utility can execute scripts only interactively, and isn't suited for batch usage.

What am I missing? How can one execute sql scripts when using oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe that the SQL*Plus utility isn't suited for batch usage?  It's pretty common to use it for running these sorts of scripts-- you can pass the script to SQL*Plus when you invoke it if you'd like, i.e.

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@someDatabase @someScript.sql
```

That is a pretty common way of deploying builds.

If the problem is with the way SQL*Plus is handling errors, you can simply add the line

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
```

to abort and throw the Oracle error number that was encountered.  The documentation for the [WHENEVER SQLERROR command](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12052.htm#i2700066) provides a number of other options as well.

Comment: I already tried this - when error occurs sqlplus just carries on with the rest of the script, which is undesirable.
 sqlplus does not return error information, no process exit code, nothing I guess it can generate log files, but do I have to parse a log file just to find out what went wrong?

Comment: You should be able to use the WHENEVER SQLERROR command to control that behavior.  See expanded answer.

Comment: OK, WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE will do the job
Thanks for the fast response!
I guess oracle takes some time to get used to

Answer (score 2):

Devdimi,

I agree with Erik K.

And yes you can include DDL in an anonymous block.

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE foo';
END;
```

Remember DDL does a commit BEFORE and AFTER it runs. So as part of a transaction it kinda sucks.

Comment: Yes it works, I just didn't know about the WHENEVER SQLERROR command.
It actually makes exactly what I need. 

I can't use anonymous procedure because of the automatic commits.

Comment: DDL automatically commits no matter where it is called from. It's the nature of DDL and Oracle. No two ways about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it if you wrap the statement inside DECLARE/BEGIN/END. I don't have access to Oracle anymore so I can't test it, though.
Example:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ...;
    UPDATE something ...;
END;
```

Since you want to execute DDL, use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: the problem is that we also have DDL, which I think can't be executed in anonymous stored procedure
But I will try that too, thanks.