# Run multiple commands in one ExecuteScalar in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, executescalar, ora-00911

I have a batch of sql statements such as ...

insert into.... ;
insert into.... ;
delete .........;

etc

When i try to execute them against oracle it gives me [this](http://ora-00911.ora-code.com/) error (ORA-00911 Invalid Character)

now i can understand that this is because of the semicolon between the statements, i tried this on SQL Server and it worked but in Oracle no luck so far.

Is there a way to run multiple statements against oracle by using the ExecuteScalar or some other function?

---

**DUPLICATE**: [How can I execute multiple Oracle SQL statements with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528676/how-can-i-execute-multiple-oracle-sql-statements-with-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping with a `BEGIN..END`

```
BEGIN insert into.... ; insert into.... ; delete .........; END;
```

Comment: worked for me in SQL Developer. After I remembered the ; after END.

Answer (score 0):

trying the BEGIN END did not work for me.

What i did was make a new method that given a connection(i try to minimize my open connections) it splits the statements using the ; as a delimiter and runs each one seperatly

```
    private void ExecuteSql(string statements, IDbConnection conn)
    {
        IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        string[] commands = statements.Split(new string[] { ";\r\n", "; ", ";\t", ";\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string c in commands)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = c;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

My inspiration came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680605/how-to-provide-a-sql-command-line-interface-like-osql-to-a-mssql-database-via-w/680772#680772) post after [Petros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2812/petros) told me about it

PS you may need to change it according to your needs, in my case i require the connection to be open, and closed accordingly if something happens from the caller.